# tengo el siguiente problema con un combobox al seleccionar una opcion

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un combobox con las opciones de cedula, ruc y pasaporte pero no logro hacer que al seleccionar cedula pueda ingresar solo 10 digitos al seleccionar ruc pueda ingresar 13 digitos y al seleccionar pasaporte sea libre hasta los momentos solo logro hacer que acepte 10 digitos y solo numeros pero me los agarra las tres opciones les muestro el codigo para que me indiquen que puedo hacer soy nuevo en esto

```
                               <!-- Lista de selección -->
                                <select id="validador" name="combo" class="btn 
                                  btn-info">

                                    <!-- Opciones de la lista -->
                  <option value="cedula"selected>Cédula</option>
                  <option value="ruc">RUC</option>
                  <option value="pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
                   </select>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && 
           event.charCode <= 57' class="form- 
                control validar-cedula" 
                id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" maxlength="10">





         //Comprobar que la Cedula solo tiene 10 digitos
             console.log('ejecutar');
              $('.validar-cedula').keypress(function(e) {
               if ($('.validar-cedula').val().length >= 12) {
                  if ($('#validador').find(":selected").val() == 'ruc') {}
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: hola, bienvenido, necesitas entonces que los tres input acepten puros números del 0 al 9? y que el total sean de 10 dígitos?

Comment: Hola, gracias no solo la cedula que sea de 10 digitos el ruc de 13 y el pasaporte libre

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta que te he dejado, si te funciona no olvides marcar como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría sería crear tres `input's` con sus respectivos `id` y ocultarlos inicialmente, después le agrego la función `change` al `select` y obtengo el valor seleccionado, con un `switch` valido y dependiendo que haya seleccionado muestro y oculto los otros dos inputs, además le agrego el atributo `maxlength` para que solo acepte en el caso de la cédula 10 digitos y en ruc 13, la funcion de hasta abajo reemplaza con una Regex los que no son dígitos por vacio `''`, espero te ayude, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#cedula').hide();
$('#ruc').hide();
$('#pasaporte').hide();

$('#validador').change(function(){
  
    
  
    switch($(this).val()){
      case 'cedula':
        $('#cedula').show();
        $('#cedula').attr("maxlength",'10');
        $('#ruc').hide();
        $('#pasaporte').hide();
      break;
      
      case 'ruc':
      $('#ruc').show();
      $('#cedula').attr("maxlength",'13');
        $('#cedula').hide();
        $('#pasaporte').hide();
      break;
      
      case 'pasaporte':
        $('#pasaporte').show();
        $('#ruc').hide();
        $('#cedula').hide();
        
      break;
      
 
    }

})



$('input').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select id="validador" name="combo" class="btn 
                                  btn-info">

                                    <!-- Opciones de la lista -->
                  <option value="">SELECCIONA</option>
                  <option value="cedula">Cédula</option>
                  <option value="ruc">RUC</option>
                  <option value="pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
                   </select>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-9">
                   <input type="text" id="cedula" placeholder="Cedula">
                   <input type="text" id="ruc" placeholder="RUC">
                   <input type="text" id="pasaporte" placeholder="Pasaporte">
                   </div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder pero me salen 3 input y necesito que sea solo 1 y al seleccionar por ejemplo cedula tenga las restricciones de ese campo igual al ser ruc

Comment: Si lees la descripción de mi respuesta te sugerí crear 3 inputs, sólo aparecerá el input de la opción que selecciones y tienen sus respectivos restricciones en cuanto a su longitud.